# Definir limitação em números aleatórios gerados

Tags: r

Eu preciso criar uma carteira de investimentos aleatória com determinados benchmarks. Inicializei ela com tudo 0.

```
structure(list(Benchmarks = structure(c(2L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 
11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 8L), .Label = c("ALOCACAO", 
"DI", "DÓLAR", "IBOV", "IDA - GERAL", "IDKA_IPCA2", "IDKA_PRE2", 
"IFIX", "IHFA", "IMA-GERAL", "IMAB", "IMAB - 5", "IMAB - 5 +", 
"IRFM", "IRFM - 1", "IRFM - 1 +", "VÉRTICE"), class = "factor"), 
    percentual = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Mas eu tenho as seguintes condições:

- A obrigação, soma dos benchmarks = 100%, não pode sobrar ou faltar.
- Nem todos os benchmarks precisam estar preenchidos, alguns podem ficar vazios

Abaxio segue a geração de um dos benchs que eu fiz

```
distribuicaoBenchmark[distribuicaoBenchmark$Benchmarks == "DI", 2] <- runif(1, min = 0, max = 100)
```

Não consegui pensar nas duas limitações. Pensei em usar um `while (totalInvestido < 100)`, mas nos meus teste, ocorria de sobrar dinheiro OU ele ficar em loop eterno pois nunca consegui satisfazer a condição do while.

Comment: As duas condições não são a mesma? A soma dos benchmarks == 100%?

Comment: Relendo agora sim, farei um edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para cada peso individual, basta selecionar um número aleatório de qualquer distribuição com suporte nos números não-negativos. Depois, divida cada peso pelo somatório de todos os pesos:

```
set.seed(1234)
distribuicaoBenchmark <- runif(17, 0, 100)
distribuicaoBenchmark <- distribuicaoBenchmark/sum(distribuicaoBenchmark)
summary(distribuicaoBenchmark)
##     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
## 0.001085 0.032701 0.069609 0.058824 0.076099 0.105501 
sum(distribuicaoBenchmark)
## [1] 1
```

Para obter os pesos entre 0 e 100, basta multiplicar `distribuicaoBenchmark` por 100.